# Interpolation of orientations

Tags: 3d

I have a problem of linear interpolation of [CRV (Conformal Rotation Vector)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=94HtCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&dq=Rigid+and+Flexible+Mechanisms+A+Finite+Element+Approach+Based+on+the+Conformal+Rotation+Vector&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Rigid%20and%20Flexible%20Mechanisms%20A%20Finite%20Element%20Approach%20Based%20on%20the%20Conformal%20Rotation%20Vector&f=false) in which CRVs are used to parameterize the orientations.

In my knowledge, in order to derive a linear interpolation of orientations, we could apply a conversion from CRV into the corresponding unit quaternion, and then a SLERP ([Spherical Linear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp)) could be performed to interpolate linearly the orientation parametrized by CRVs.

My question is: Could we derive an interpolation of quality directly using CRVs (in linear scope)?

Comment: You can slerp a quaternion by repeatedly nlerping to 0.5 and binary searching. So if you can expand out the math of conversion to quaternion, the nlerp and the conversion back, then it should be possible

Comment: More generally, if you can lerp from the identity to any rotation $r$, i.e. find the rotation $r^t$ with the same axis and $t$ times the angle, then you can lerp from $a$ to $b$ via $(ba^{-1})^ta$.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments, Ratchet Freak and Rahul! I will take your advice and answer this question.